# What happens to const variables within an object when it gets destroyed?

Tags: angular, memory, constants

I'm just curious to know whether following tslint all the way through faithfully is ok as it advices me to use const instead of let when not reassigned (which makes sense). Although I've heard another developer tell me that using const is bad as it can't get garbage collected to clear memory.

I want to get a better understanding of the dangers of using const within my objects. I'm worried about it in the example below to know if I'm causing memory leaks within my Angular App.

E.g. In an Angular app:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

class MyComponentObject {
   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.queryParams$ = this.activatedRoute
        .queryParamMap
        .map(params => {

         // is this bad?
         const something = params.get('something') || null;

      })
   }
}
```

Will the const still remain on destroying the object (ngDestory). Will it in some way get built up on memory over and over again with each initialization of this class?

So generally is it ok memory wise to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` just means you cannot reassign the variable. It has nothing to do with garbage collection.

In your snippet the variable will be destroyed when the `ngOnInit` function terminates. By then the value it had will be eligible for garbage collection (unless it is referenced somewhere else as well).