# What happens to a const in for loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, memory

Not too long ago I asked a question about using const in objects.
[What happens to const variables within an object when it gets destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521139/what-happens-to-const-variables-within-an-object-when-it-gets-destroyed/46521187#46521187)

Then I noticed that tslint is advising me to also use it in for loops (which is a statement instead of an object). I'm just curious what are the implications if I'm iterating a massive object in terms of memory. Do my constants get piled up somewhere as hidden loop closures if I assign them a large object in an array or are they completely unset and garbaged collected with each loop?

```
let reallyMassiveHeavylist = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
];

for (const reallyBigitem of reallyMassiveHeavylist) {
  // will there be leftover growing up to 4 {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, from
  // the last const used in previous iterations?
  // Will it remain in the objects memory/scope after the loop?

  console.log(reallyBigItem);
}
```

So basically:
1. After the loop is finished do the **constants** stay in memory until the parent-scope/object it's in become destoryed.
2. Is there a leftover build up on the constants in memory as the loop iterates, or is it just one constant only in memory per loop?

Comment: It's not a question related to TypeScript. I replace the tag by `javascript`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the correction.

Comment: To answer to your question, `const` is the same as `let`. It is a way to declare a variable (but with `const` the variable cannot be reassigned). If you replace `const` by `let` in your code, does your question remain?